# Laravel - carbon problem showing on the blade

Tags: php, laravel, date, if-statement

I have this car project and I need to show some date of car info at my table. So this is my code:

```
<?php $today = Carbon\Carbon::now(); ?>
@if($car->po_datum_isteka == $today)
<td>{{$car->naslov}}</td>
<td class="text-info"><a href="">{{$car->user->name}}</a></td>
<td>{{$car->created_at->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')}}</td>
@endif
```

So with this code it is not showing anything but with this:

```
<?php $today = Carbon\Carbon::now(); ?>
@if($car->po_datum_isteka <= $today)
<td>{{$car->naslov}}</td>
<td class="text-info"><a href="">{{$car->user->name}}</a></td>
<td>{{$car->created_at->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')}}</td>
@endif
```

it shows. The difference is between `==` and `<=`. Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$car->po_datum` is probably less than `now()`. Hint: You can remove `<?php $today = Carbon\Carbon::now(); ?>` and just use `@if($car->po_datum_isteka == now())`.

Comment: Are you trying to compare dates only, or with time as well?

Comment: @Qirel it is not showing anything again. I just want to show results for today, because ```po_datum_isteka``` is equal to ```Carbon::today()```, so I need to display every car where it's ```po_datum_isteka``` is todays date

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `now()` returns the current date and time. Which means that you need `$car->po_datum_isteka` to be the exact same date *and* time of day.

Instead, you can just use the `isToday()` method.

```php
@if ($car->po_datum_isteka->isToday())
    <td>{{ $car->naslov }}</td>
    <td class="text-info"><a href="">{{ $car->user->name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ $car->created_at->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
@endif
```

This assumes that `$car->naslov` is an instance of Carbon, which you can ensure by casting it in your model (I'm assuming you have a model called Cars here).

If `$car->po_datum_isteka` is not an instance of Carbon, you can always just parse it.

```php
@if (\Carbon\Carbon::parse($car->po_datum_isteka)->isToday())
    <td>{{ $car->naslov }}</td>
    <td class="text-info"><a href="">{{ $car->user->name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ $car->created_at->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
@endif
```

Comment: It gives me this error ```"Call to a member function isToday() on string"``` what should I do?

Comment: See my edited answer. Your property is not a Carbon object, but a string, so you need to parse it into an object first.